# Mysql partition indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing, partitioning

I want to create a table from batch data for data mining purposes. I will have about 25 million rows of data a day  going into this table. There are several indices defined on the table, so the insertion (I do batch insertions) speed is quite slow. With no indices I can stick 40K rows, while with indices it is more like 3-4 K, which makes this whole thing infeasible. So the idea is to partition the data by day, disable the keys, and then do the day's insertions, and reenable the indices. Reenabling indices on a day's worth of data takes, say, 20 minutes, which is fine. This takes me to my question. When you reenable the indices, will it have to recalculate the indices on all partions, or just for that day? It seems clear that for the index that the partitions are on (date in this case), it should be for that day only. But how about the other indices? If it needs to recalculate the indices for all partitions, there is no way it can be done in a reasonable amount of time. Does anyone know?

Show create is like this:

```
sts | CREATE TABLE `sts` (
`userid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`urlid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`geoid` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`cid` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`m` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`t` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`d` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`requested` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`rate` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`mode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`session` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`sins` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`tos` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userid, urlid, requested),
KEY `id_index` (`m`),
KEY `id_index2` (`t`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It is not currently partitioned.

Comment: What is your current table structure? (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`)

Answer (score 0):

You disable/enable index on a **table**. It means that index will be disabled/enables on all parts of the table.

Consider this scenario for loading new data:

1. Create a staging table defining all partitions you will need
2. Load data into staging table without indexes.
3. Create indexes on this table.
4. Move partition to target table, which is partitioned same as staging table.
5. Drop indexes on staging table

To partition your existing data in controllable manner you can use same logic to move data to new partitioned table.